# I am unable to adjust the height of the page for my website

Tags: html, css

[Homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCaPT.png)

[image]

The attached image has the page which I am designing.
Here, I have written the following CSS :

```
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
```

While the width works fine, the height does not occupy the whole section of the screen.

I tested it on a smaller screen of 19 inches where it looks fine. I have a 21 inch screen where I face this issue.
Is there any way I can make this page to occupy the whole page irrespective of the screen size ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the full `100% height` of the screen you need to set all elements to be the 100% including `html` and `body`. Try this on your CSS:

```
html,body {
   height:100%;
}
.yourcontainer, .insidelements {
   height:100%;
}
```

Comment: I tried it. But i have few issues. Basically, I have divided that <div> into 3 parts : the top (brown section), the middle (text section) and the bottom (brown part). Therefore , when I add the CSS you gave , I get the bottom part to be way long and there appears a scroll on the webpage.

Comment: @prat1kk then add some more code and if you can a live example

Comment: <div class="containter">
 <div class="header">
<div class="headerImg">
 </div>
 <div class="menuDiv">
 <a href="" class="menuItem">COVERS</a>
 <a href="" class="menuItem">ORIGINALS</a>
<a href="" class="menuItem">JINGLES</a>
<br style="clear: both;">
                </div>
            </div>
<div class="footerImg">
<div align="bottom"></div>
 </div>
 </div>